# How can i count comparisons are made when i try to enter a new key in a hash map?

Tags: java, dictionary, hash, hashmap, hashtable

I want to make a method to count how many comparisons are made when i want to put a new random key in my hash map . The code I used to put new keys in the map is the following :

```
public void put(int key, int value) { 
          int hash = (key % table.length);
          int initialHash = -1;
          int indexOfDeletedEntry = -1;

          while (hash != initialHash
                      && (table[hash] == DeletedEntry.getUniqueDeletedEntry()
                      || table[hash] != null
                      && table[hash].getKey() != key)) {
                if (initialHash == -1)
                      initialHash = hash;
                if (table[hash] == DeletedEntry.getUniqueDeletedEntry())
                      indexOfDeletedEntry = hash;
                hash = (hash + 1) % table.length;
          }
          if ((table[hash] == null || hash == initialHash)
                      && indexOfDeletedEntry != -1) {
                table[indexOfDeletedEntry] = new HashEntry(key, value);
                size++;
          } else if (initialHash != hash)
                if (table[hash] != DeletedEntry.getUniqueDeletedEntry()
                           && table[hash] != null && table[hash].getKey() == key)
                      table[hash].setValue(value);
                else {
                      table[hash] = new HashEntry(key, value);
                      size++;
                }
          if (size >= maxSize)
                resize();
    }
```

The class for the deleted entry is the following :

```
public class DeletedEntry extends HashEntry {

    private static DeletedEntry entry = null;

    private DeletedEntry() {
          super(-1, -1);
    }

    public static DeletedEntry getUniqueDeletedEntry() {
          if (entry == null)
                entry = new DeletedEntry();
          return entry;
    }

}
```

Also , HashEntry class has 2 int variables , int key and int value .
Any Idea how i can count the comparisons ?
This is what I've done in my main:

```
Random rand = new Random();
        int[] comparisons = new int[20]; 

        int key = 0;

        for (int k=0;k<20;k++){
            key = rand.nextInt(1000) + 1; 
        }
```

Comment: Comparisons of what? 
Take a look into writing a java agent to instrument the bytecode of the HashMap class.

Comment: @Roman comparisons made when i try to put new keys

Comment: @AsukaMatseli Are you manually implementing your own `HashMap`, are you aware that `Java` already has an implementation?

Comment: @BlakeYarbrough yes but it's for an academic project so i have to do it on my own ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own `CustomHashMap`

In this `CustomHashMap` you can implement a new `put()` method that keeps count of the comparisons and then returns that value.

```
public int put(int key, int value) { 
          int hash = (key % table.length);
          int initialHash = -1;
          int indexOfDeletedEntry = -1;
          int numberOfComparisons = 1;

          while (hash != initialHash
                      && (table[hash] == DeletedEntry.getUniqueDeletedEntry()
                      || table[hash] != null
                      && table[hash].getKey() != key)) {
                numberOfComparisons++;
                if (initialHash == -1)
                      initialHash = hash;
                if (table[hash] == DeletedEntry.getUniqueDeletedEntry())
                      indexOfDeletedEntry = hash;
                hash = (hash + 1) % table.length;
          }
          if ((table[hash] == null || hash == initialHash)
                      && indexOfDeletedEntry != -1) {
                table[indexOfDeletedEntry] = new HashEntry(key, value);
                size++;
          } else if (initialHash != hash)
                if (table[hash] != DeletedEntry.getUniqueDeletedEntry()
                           && table[hash] != null && table[hash].getKey() == key)
                      table[hash].setValue(value);
                else {
                      table[hash] = new HashEntry(key, value);
                      size++;
                }
          if (size >= maxSize)
                resize();
          return numberOfComparisons;
 }
```

Comment: Taking another look at OPs code, it's most likely an entirely custom implementation

Answer (score 1):

<sup>(I'm assuming that this is a learning exercise of some kind.  Hence advice to use or extend an existing `Map` implementation is irrelevant.)</sup>

The simple answer is that you increment a counter each time you "compare" keys.  You could do that inline, or you could write yourself a little helper method like this:

```
  private boolean compareKeys(int key1, int key2) {
      count++;
      return key1 == key2;
  }
```

and then change your code to use this helper each time it compares keys; e.g.

```
  while (hash != initialHash
              && (table[hash] == DeletedEntry.getUniqueDeletedEntry()
              || table[hash] != null
              && !compareKeys(table[hash].getKey(), key))) {
```

and

```
  if (table[hash] != DeletedEntry.getUniqueDeletedEntry()
       && table[hash] != null 
       && compareKeys(table[hash].getKey(), key))
```

There really is no clever solution to this problem.